# COUNT не считывает 0 с JOIN

Tags: mysql, count

Такие вопросы много задавались. Возможно у меня не правильный запрос или я что то делаю не так, потому что все ответы на подобные вопросы которые я видел не работают.

У меня есть таблица **tags**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И есть таблица со связкой связка с tag_id и id_product - **bund_tags**

[image: ![![введите сюда описание изображения]

И я решил, посчитать количество привязанных **id_product** к **tag_id**.
Вот на таблице видно, что к тегу под id **4** привязаны **4** (id_product) товара. И т.д

Делаю mysql запрос:

```
SELECT tags.tag_id, tag_title, count(id_product) as num_product FROM tags INNER JOIN bund_tags ON tags.tag_id = bund_tags.tag_id GROUP BY tags.tag_id
```

Я новичок в mysql и не уверен что пишу правильно. Написал как мог.
Но главное что у меня выводиться следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но вот, есть такие теги (id_tag) у которых нет привязок id_product, и поэтому я не понимаю как сделать так, что бы мне выводилось 0 в `as num_product` если ни одной привязки нет.

Я пробовал следующие:

```
COALESCE(count(id_product), 0)
ISNULL - вообще не работает
```

Возможно я вообще все накосячил.
Помогите пожалуйста, какие есть варианты?

Comment: Вместо INNER JOIN используйте LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Mike спасибо что ответили и особенно помогли! Видимо такое простое решение а я и не узнал.